# Shell script won't run properly when re-assigning variable

Tags: linux, shell

So I've got a shell script to do some lazy stuff for if the directory isn't changing for a user. It's below. Essentially, it should be an if statement that if the user enters "default" for the directory, it'll pull them to the default directory for the files. However, I'm getting a `command not found` on line 16, which is the reassignment statement.

The entire `if` statement below:

```
if [ $directory = "default" ];
then 
    echo Enter your ldap:
    read $ldap
    $directory = "/usr/local/home/google/${ldap}/Downloads"
fi
```

I've tried doing it without the dollar sign too...nothing. What's going on here? New to shell, couldn't find this question asked before either.

Comment: Consider cleaning up the issues found by [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) first

Comment: Note that there are two separate duplicates flagged -- one regards the whitespace, the other regards the leading `$`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should assign a value to a variable in shell:

```
directory="/usr/local/home/google/${ldap}/Downloads"
```

- No dollar (`$`) sign.
- No space around equal (`=`) sign.

---

Also, you should wrap your variables inside double quotes (`"`). This way, you avoid errors with undefined variables, arguments with spaces, etc.

---

That gives us:

```
if [ "$directory" = "default" ]
then
    echo "Enter your ldap:"
    read $ldap
    directory="/usr/local/home/google/${ldap}/Downloads"
fi
```

Comment: Didn't know spaces affected this - included spaces for readability. Thank you!

Comment: @RonanBoiteau, see the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), third bullet point, regarding questions which "have been asked and answered many times before".